# Sorting into separate lists with Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am new to angular and programming and need some guidance and help learning. I have an html page that has 5 tabs, "Who", "What", "Where", "When", and "Events". I have the following code. How do I take the json category entries in my controller and separate them into the html tab that relates to it? I appreciate any help.

```
//html
<div id="chartsContainer" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

            <div id="" class="row">
                <h3 class="pull-left" style="color:white">CHARTS</h3>
                <form ng-submit="filterCharts()" class="pull-right">
                    <!-- Single button -->
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        all <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Used</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Unused</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="tabMasterContainer" ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">

                <tabset vertical="false" type="navType">
                <tab heading="Who">
                <a ng-click="groupBy( 'category' )">Category</a>
                        <div id="chartsList" class="row">

                            <div id="" class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue; height:100px; margin: 10px;" ng-repeat="chart in charts">

                                <p><i class="fa {{chart.icon}} fa-2x" style="color:white"></i></p>
                                <p style="color:white"> {{chart.description}} </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </tab>
                <tab heading="What">
                    <div id="tabContainer">
                    <div id="" class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue; height:100px; margin: 10px;" ng-repeat="chart in charts">
                                <p><i class="fa {{chart.icon}} fa-2x" style="color:white"></i></p>
                                <p style="color:white"> {{chart.description}} </p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </tab>
                <tab heading="When">
                    <div id="tabContainer">
               <div id="" class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue; height:100px; margin: 10px;" ng-repeat="chart in charts">
                                <p><i class="fa {{chart.icon}} fa-2x" style="color:white"></i></p>
                                <p style="color:white"> {{chart.description}} </p>
                            </div>
                    </div>                  
                </tab>
                <tab heading="Where">
                    <div id="tabContainer">
                <div id="" class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue; height:100px; margin: 10px;" ng-repeat="chart in charts">
                                <p><i class="fa {{chart.icon}} fa-2x" style="color:white"></i></p>
                                <p style="color:white"> {{chart.description}} </p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </tab>
                <tab heading="Events">
                    <div id="tabContainer">
                <div id="" class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue; height:100px; margin: 10px;" ng-repeat="chart in charts">
                                <p><i class="fa {{chart.icon}} fa-2x" style="color:white"></i></p>
                                <p style="color:white"> {{chart.description}} </p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </tab>

              </tabset>
            </div>


    </div>
  </div>




$scope.charts = [
        { id : 1, description: "Date Range", icon : "fa-camera-retro",         category : "When"},

        { id : 2, description: "Time of Day", icon : "fa-cog", category :     "When"},
        { id : 3, description: "Day of Week", icon : "fa-bar-chart-o", category : "When"},
        { id : 4, description: "Age Range", icon : "fa-wrench", category : "Who"},
        { id : 5, description: "who foo", icon : "fa-wrench", category : "Who"},
        { id : 6, description: "what foo", icon : "fa-wrench", category : "What"},
        { id : 7, description: "what foo", icon : "fa-wrench", category : "What"},
        { id : 8, description: "where foo", icon : "fa-wrench", category : "Where"},
        { id : 9, description: "where foo", icon : "fa-wrench", category : "Where"},
        { id : 10, description: "basketball foo", icon : "fa-wrench", category : "Events"},
        { id : 11, description: "Doctor Who Foo", icon : "fa-wrench", category : "Events"},
        { id : 12, description: "You foo", icon : "fa-wrench", category : "Who"},
        { id : 13, description: "Boo foo", icon : "fa-wrench", category : "Events"},
        { id : 14, description: "da bar", icon : "fa-rocket", category : "Where"}
    ]
```

I know that I need to iterate through the json, so I wrote this

```
function chartFinder(chartArray, id){
for (var i = 0; i < chartArray.length; ++i) {
    if(id==chartArray[i].key)
       return id[i].value;
}
```

};

Comment: The html didn't post correctly. Here it is again:

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to edit...I am definitely a NOOB right out of school. I appreciate any opportunity to learn!!

Comment: fiddles are are an easy way for us to help... hint hint.

Comment: I will use fiddle in the future. Thank you for the tip :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way.  For each category do the below.  Add a filter and it will automatically do it for you.

```
ng-repeat="chart in charts|filter:{category: 'Where'}"
```

Comment: How would I do the same thing in jquery?

Comment: I created the tab menu using jquery. Here is my fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/cg085b/35NJc/ 
I have tried to use the ng-repeat="chart in charts|filter:{category: 'Where'}" loop with this to get the charts in the correct tab, but it doesn't work. How would I get the charts to filter in to the correct tab?

Comment: So... I dont see any angular code here ... :)   If you give me a more organized question I can probably help.

Comment: lol...I switched to jquery. My boss kept changing his mind. I was able to make a custom nav tab menu. Thank you for all of your help!!